# Use dayfirst unless yearfirst is true

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I'm using `dateutil.parser.parse` to parse dates from a text file.

I don't know in advance whether the dates will be `YYYY-MM-DD` (ISO style) or UK style `DD-MM-YYYY` (or other separators in the UK case.)

If I use [dayfirst](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html?highlight=dayfirst#dateutil.parser.parse) it will parse the UK style correctly, but parse the ISO-style incorrectly as `YYYY-DD-MM`.

How can I specify that it's dayfirst *unless* it's yearfirst?

Comment: Why can't you filter your strings by the length of `s.split('-', 1)[0]` and then apply the parser?

Comment: Yeah, that would be ok. I mean, there are probably a million hacky ways to solve this particular problem. I _could_ parse the dates myself... I wondered if there was a non-hacky way.

Answer (score 1):

Would looking at the first four digits of the input be enough to determine if it's in ISO format?

```
from dateutil.parser import *


def convert_date(date_string):

    if date_string[0:4].isdigit():
        return parse(date_string)
    else:
        return parse(date_string, dayfirst=True)


print(convert_date('2020-06-05'))
# 2020-06-05 00:00:00
print(convert_date('05-06-2020'))
# 2020-06-05 00:00:00
```